# How rootkits hide a specified process?

Tags: rootkits

I heard that a rootkit can hide itself and specified files, processes, and network links.

I know it can set a file to be hidden, but how does it hide a process?

Such as, there is a `httpd` process running so that `ps -ef` does not show the `httpd` process.

Comment: Um, it's called a "process", not a progress :) Your question is "how do rootkits work", and that's a bit broad. There's different answers to that, because they do different things. You'll have to be more specific.

Comment: I think now that you have the correct search terms, this is will be easier to look up.